# Eclipse/adb/DDMS: Samsung S2 4.0.3 not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb, ddms

I use two devices to develop my Android apps:

- a Samsung tablet Galaxy tab 10.1 (Android 3.1)
- a Samsung S2 (Android 4.0.3)

I develop on Mac OSX Lion.

My problem is that my Samusung S2 is not recognized by Eclipse (everything is ok with my tablet!!). To be more accurate, my S2 appears something like 1 second every 1 minute in DDMS or the "Android Device Chooser" (the window which appears when you launch the app in Eclipse and where you can choose between a physical device or emulator) and then disappears !!! This is driving me crazy.

I tried absolutely everything I found on forums:

- update all modules via the SDK Manager
- update of Eclipse via Help => check for updates
- tried 3 different USB cables...
- tried to reset adb either via DDMS or in command line (adb kill-server and then adb start-server)
- I checked that USB debugging is set on my S2

Can the rubbish Samsung app "Kies" induce some issues? (not the case with my tablet) Other idea?

Can anybody help me ???!!!

Thanks !!

Comment: The only thing close to this I've seen is a low end Samsung device I used to test with. It would only be picked up by adb the first time after a phone reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I had a physical problem with the micro-USB connection on my Samsung S2... I returned it to Samsung and they repaired it ! it seems that the micro-USB connection on S2 are very fragile...especially when you connect/disconnect very often your device !! Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Use Kies to force a reinstall of the drivers.

In Kies (Version 2.3.2.12054_20):

- Tools > Troubleshoot connection error.
- Follow the wizard (there is a "Reinstall device driver" stage).

I don't have a special confidence this will fix your problem. I offer it as something to try.

Comment: I use Mac OSX ; are you sure that I have to deal with drivers ? Normally, everything works directly.

Comment: No I'm not sure you have to deal with drivers. I don't use Macs at all. On Mac, in Kies, does "Tools > Troubleshoot connection error" do anything? Does the command exist?

Comment: No this command doesn't exist on Mac OSX. I tested it on my PC ; this command has a very strange behaviour: very long process (I really wonder what this stupid app Kies does during these long minutes) and I am asked at the beginning of this process to unplug my device...I don't understand how a connection can be repaired if my device is not connected. I hate Kies!!